# How to use one class attribute of a class as a type inside another class in pydantic?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class A(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[str]
    c: bool = False

class B(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: Optional[str]
    c:  #I want to add the attribute "c" from class A as a type here
```

How do I use attribute "c" from class A as a type inside class B?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you'd want to subclass from `A` like below (overriding the type annotations in `A` if needed):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional


class A(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[str]
    c: bool = False

class B(A, BaseModel):
    a: str


print(B(a=123, c=True))
# a='123' b=None c=True
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional, List

class A(BaseModel):
   a: int
   b: Optional[str]
   c: bool = False

class B(BaseModel):
   a: str
   b: Optional[str]
   c: List(A)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).